# Angularjs - optimizing the watcher of ngrepeat to watch only certain properties of collection

Tags: performance, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my angularJS application I have a collection (array) of rather large objects. I need to bind to this collection in various places (e.g. to display the property: name of the contained objects) - binding is essential, as these names might change.

As the normal ngRepeat would observe the whole collection by strict equality comparison I am concerned about application speed (we are talking about objects with thousends of properties or more) - I actually just need to observe general changes in the collection (like length, changes of the single references in case two elements are flipped and some specific properties like the mentioned .name property)

I am thinking about using the following approach (basically creating a custom copy of the collection and manually bind to the original collection.

**My question:**
Is the described approach better than watching the original collection (by equality - as it is my understanding the ngRepeater does) or is there some better approach (e.g. defining some kind of compare callback in a watch statement to check only for changes in certain properties,...)

```
<script>
function QuickTestController($scope) {
    // simulate data from a service
    var serviceCollection = [], counter = 0,
        generateElement = function() {
            var element = { name:'name' + ++counter };
            //var element = { name:'name' };
            for (var j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) element['property' + j] = j;

            return element;
        };

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        serviceCollection.push( generateElement() );
    }

    // in the view controller we could either bind to the service collection directly (which should internally use a watchCollection and watch every single element for equality)
    $scope.viewCollection = serviceCollection;

    // watching equality of collection
    /*
    $scope.$watch('_viewCollectionObserve', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('watch: ', newValue, oldValue);
    }, true);
    */

    // or we could create our own watchCollection / watch structure and watch only those properties we are interested in
    $scope._viewCollectionObserve = serviceCollection;

    var viewCollectionManual = [],
        rebuildViewCollection = function() {
            viewCollectionManual = [];
            for (var i = 0, length = serviceCollection.length ; i < length ; i++) {
                viewCollectionManual.push( {name:serviceCollection[i].name } );
            }
            console.log('- rebuildViewCollection - ');
            $scope.viewCollection2 = viewCollectionManual;
        },
        watchCollectionProperties = [],
        unregisterWatchCollection = function() {},
        rebuildWatchCollectionProperties = function() {
            watchCollectionProperties = [];
            for (var i = 0, length = serviceCollection.length ; i < length ; i++) {
                watchCollectionProperties.push('_viewCollectionObserve[' + i + ']'); // watch for ref changes
                watchCollectionProperties.push('_viewCollectionObserve[' + i + '].name'); // watch for changes in specific properties
            }
            unregisterWatchCollection();
            var watchString = '[' + watchCollectionProperties.join(',') + ']';
            unregisterWatchCollection = $scope.$watchCollection(watchString, function(newValues, oldValues) {
                console.log('watchCollection: ', newValues, oldValues);
                rebuildViewCollection();
            });
        };

        $scope.$watch('_viewCollectionObserve.length', function(newValue, oldValue) { // watch add / remove elements to / from collection
            console.log('watch / length: ', newValue, oldValue);
            rebuildWatchCollectionProperties();
        });


        // rebuildViewCollection();
        rebuildWatchCollectionProperties();


    // click handler ---
    $scope.changName = function() { serviceCollection[0].name += '1'; };
    $scope.changeSomeProperty = function() { serviceCollection[0].property0 += 1; };
    $scope.removeElement = function() { serviceCollection.splice(0, 1); };
    $scope.addElement = function() { serviceCollection.push( generateElement() ); };
    $scope.switchElement = function() {
        var temp = serviceCollection[0];
        serviceCollection[0] = serviceCollection[1];
        serviceCollection[1] = temp;
    };
    // will of course not react to this (this is desired behaviour!)
    $scope.removeCollection = function() {  serviceCollection = []; };
}
</script>

<div data-ng-controller="QuickTestController">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="element in viewCollection">{{element.name}} {{element}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="element in viewCollection2">{{element.name}} {{element}}</li>
    </ul>

    <button data-ng-click="changName()">changName</button>
    <button data-ng-click="changeSomeProperty()">changeSomeProperty</button>
    <button data-ng-click="removeElement()">removeElement</button>
    <button data-ng-click="addElement()">addElement</button>
    <button data-ng-click="switchElement()">switchElement</button>
    <hr>
    <button data-ng-click="removeCollection()">removeCollection (see comment)</button>  
</div>
```

Any help / opinions would be greatly appreciated - please note that I tried to create a fiddle to demonstrate my approach but failed :-(

(I know that benchmarking might be a possible solution to test my approach, but I´d rather know the opinion of the angularjs pros in here)

thanks,
matthias

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), which is a high performance binding directive that lets you bind a property or expression once in AngularJS, just as what its name suggests.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I am however aware of the directive(s) you mentioned, and though the angularjs team even seems to intent to include this very functionality in the core in a future release, bindonce is no solution here, as it has no option for ngRepeat and removes the actual binding after the inital compile/build phase - which would prevent any further updates of the list (as demonstrated in my example) - regards, matthias

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can also try is a 'track by' expression. If you have a property that is unique for each object in the collection, you can pass that to your repeat expression.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"></div>
```

I think Angular will then just watch that property on each of your items. So this should improve performance, but I don't know how much.

Comment: thanks for your reply - as I have experienced it the track by expression part primarily comes in handy when you´re dealing with expensive DOM creation - as demonstraded in http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm - regards, matthias